# Return newtonsoft json object from WebMethod

Tags: c#, json.net, webmethod

I want to return a JSON object from a c# webmethod if i use return i have an error "recussive reference found". So i decided to use newtonsoft serialize but the returned object are in double quote. {d:"my json"} and didn't work.

I try to use this code :

```
       [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static void RecordList(int jtStartIndex = 0, int jtPageSize = 0, string jtSorting = null)
    {
        string error;
        var result = DataTools.Data("select id_individu,nom_indiv from individu limit 10",
            WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TabloidConnection"].ConnectionString,
            out error);

        var rep = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        rep.Clear();
        rep.ClearContent();
        rep.BufferOutput = true;
        rep.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";


        //rep.Write("ab");
        rep.Write("{d:");
        rep.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new jTableResponse(result), Formatting.None));
        rep.Write("}");
        rep.Flush();
        //rep.SuppressContent = true;
        rep.End();
        //ct.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();          

    }

public class jTableResponse
{

    private int totalRecordCount=0;
    private DataTable records;
    private string result = "OK";

    public string Result
    {
        get { return result; }
        set { result = value; }
    }

    public int TotalRecordCount
    {
        get { return totalRecordCount; }
        set { totalRecordCount = value; }
    }

    public DataTable Records
    {
        get { return records; }
        set { records = value; }
    }


    public jTableResponse(DataTable r)
    {
        Records = r;
        totalRecordCount = r.Rows.Count;
    }
}
```

But i have character added behind and after my json like this (using fiddler)

1d0
{d:{"Result":"OK","TotalRecordCount":10,"Records":[{"id_individu":1,"nom_indiv":"..."},{"id_individu":2,"nom_indiv":"RIVET"},{"id_individu":3,"nom_indiv":"COHEN"},{"id_individu":4,"nom_indiv":"VILLEROUGE"},{"id_individu":5,"nom_indiv":"CAILLARD"},{"id_individu":6,"nom_indiv":"DE CHEVRON VILLETTE"},{"id_individu":7,"nom_indiv":"ROYO"},{"id_individu":8,"nom_indiv":"ROQUES"},{"id_individu":9,"nom_indiv":"GUILLOT"},{"id_individu":10,"nom_indiv":"DORNE-CORRAZE"}]}}
0

Thanks for your response

Comment: The return looks like valid Json to me. What exactly is your question or what isn't working as you would expect? What do you expect the returned object to look like?

Comment: it start by something looking like the json length (1d0) and finish by à 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i change this

```
rep.Write("{d:");
rep.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new jTableResponse(result), Formatting.None));
rep.Write("}");
```

by this

```
rep.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new jTableResponse(result), Formatting.None));
```

it work fine thanks.